# Can I improve excel to sql powerquery performance? I'm using named range parameters instead of cell values?

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerquery

This is my first post so I hope I get my question across OK.

I have designed a product configurator app in excel. Using a series of drop down menus and user forms I can build a basic front elevation of what my product will look like whilst also deriving a list of sub assembly names that will make up the product. This sub assembly list can be viewed on a hidden worksheet. There could be over 200 of these required to make up the product.

(e.g. My product could be made up of up to 16 Sections. Each Section could have 15 different sub assemblies. So my full product could have a combination of ~240 different sub assemblies, depending on the specific requirements.)

I have named cells on the sub assembly worksheet where the sub assembly is stored. This sub assembly name is dynamic depending on selections in the configurator.

(e.g.
Cell name - ARE_Section01
Dynamic sub assembly name in cell - 
AU_ARE_36_36_GA11_AL3_X_13_3__ANSI_61_
or
AU_ARE_22_36_GA11_GA11_R_13_3__ANSI_61_
or
AU_ARE_22_36_GA11_GA11_X_13_3__ANSI_61_
or
etc.)

[image: Sample image]

In order to build a top level bill of materials I am pulling information from an SQL Server where there is a table for every possible sub assembly (over 700 of them). Using PowerQuery, I have a query for each of the 15 sub assemblies mentioned above for each of the 16 sections. In these queries I am using a parameter that looks at the relevant named cell value rather than a hard coded value. This means I will only have 240 queries rather than 700+.

(e.g.
let
    Source = Sql.Database("x_BJMCC\SQLEXPRESS", "AMX"),
    dbo_AU_ARE_22_36_GA11_GA11_R_13_3__ANSI_61_ = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item=**GetValue("ARE_Section01")**]}[Data]
in
    dbo_AU_ARE_22_36_GA11_GA11_R_13_3__ANSI_61_
)

I then have a query for each of the 16 Sections which appends all the relevant sub assemblies. I then have a top level Panel query that appends all Section queries.

I hope I have explained this properly so far.....

My problem is this...

When I hard code the assembly names into the queries the information gets pulled very quickly from SQL. But when I use the parameters (as above) its a lot slower.

Has anyone got any tips on how I can improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the problem is with your GetValue function. For example, using [fnGetParameter](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/) function by Ken Puls doesn't break query folding.

Comment: Cheers. I've had a read of that and added a comment. Using the GetValue function still allows me to see the "View Native Query" option which I've been led to believe means query folding is happening